# Is there a way to get data from sensors from command line?

Tags: android

In Android, I know it's possible to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` to execute native command line on android system like `echo` or `ls`.
I wonder if is there is any way to get data from any sensor module (like photo or gps) not from Android API (through Java or Kotlin), but by executing a command line with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Technically all that the Android framework ( + HAL ) does is communicate via system calls with the kernel.

It would certainly be possible for you to write a binary ( C/C++) that does that communication for you, bypassing the framework.
And then you could call that binary with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` ( assuming rooted and have access ).

There aren't many tools to access the sensors like that ( expect maybe some vendors might have for testing).  The only thing that comes to mind that you could use to get `some` information is by calling `dumpsys` in shell. This will give you lots of info about the current state of the system, and for example some location data as explaind in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85279/a-way-to-get-location-coordinates-from-command-line)

Comment: ok, so there is no pre-compiled executable ship with kernel made for android. We would have to found the c++ adequate lib and build an exec to make that layer available to shell. ok thx

Answer (score 0):

You can pack binary executables into your apk and launch them via Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...). Depending on the data you want to read it may be possible to implement an C/C++ program which reads /proc or /dev. If you completely statically link this executable (use i.e. musl libc) you can call it from your android app to read the data you need.